# ¿Cómo puedo bloquear un RadioButuon usando ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aplicación-web, razor

Cómo se puede bloquear un par de radiobuton:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.TipoEscala, false, new { onchange = "BloquearAlgo(true)" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(pX => pX.TipoEscala2, false, new { onchange = "BloquearAlgo(false)" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Agregando `disabled = "disabled"` se pueden bloquear/deshabilitar los controles para que queden de la siguiente forma:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.TipoEscala, false, new { onchange = "BloquearAlgo(true)", disabled = "disabled" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(pX => pX.TipoEscala2, false, new { onchange = "BloquearAlgo(false)", disabled = "disabled" })
```